# Untar bz2 to Microsd fails

Tags: ubuntu, tar, micro-sd-card, bzip2

I am trying to uncompress tar.bz2 file to ext3 formatted MicroSD card and after copying some files to card I see below errors and tar fails with below errors

```
    tar: ./usr/lib/gcc/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/4.8.2/cc1: Wrote only 8704 of 10240 bytes
        2 tar: ./usr/lib/gcc/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/4.8.2/cc1: Cannot utime: Read-only file system
        3 tar: ./usr/lib/gcc/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/4.8.2/cc1: Cannot change ownership to uid 0, gid 0: Read-only file system
        4 tar: ./usr/lib/gcc/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/4.8.2/cc1: Cannot change mode to rwxr-xr-x: Read-only file system
....
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

When this error happened MicroSD card has enough capactiy

```
Filesystem     Type  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdd1      ext3   29G  910M   27G   4% /media/lager_fs
```

I am able to untar the bz2 to my local filesystem. How can I fix this issue to untar it directly to MicroSD card?

Comment: From your own post: **Read-only file system**.   The filesystem is either RO to start with an nothing gets written or something causes it to change to RO.

Comment: @Hennes Yes it looks like that. Before this error I was able to write to the card but after this error I cannot write unless I unmount remove and insert the card again

Comment: Can you write other files to the card?

Comment: @Hennes No I cannot write any files after this error

Comment: Can you write any files to the card after a clean mount and before trying to bunzup? If not the problem has nothing to do with gzip.

Comment: Yes I am able to write to it after mount and before running tar to uncompress. I tried untar bz2 to local file system and then copy to card the contents from local file system. That too fails and card goes to read only mode but mount command says it is still in rw mode. I guess this is problem with the card.